# Finding all group homomorphisms $(\mathbb{Q},+)\to (\mathbb{Q}-\lbrace 0\rbrace,\cdot)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-homomorphism

If $f$ is such a homomorphism, then $f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)$.
I know of examples of $f$ which satisfy this property, such as $f(x)=e^x$, but how do I find all of them?

Comment: $e^x$ is not $\mathbb Q\to\mathbb Q$.

Comment: Maybe this fact will become handy: such an homomorphism cannot be onto.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is exactly one such homomorphism, namely the constant map $x\mapsto 1$, because $1$ is the only number whose $k$th roots are all rational. In more detail:

Let $x$ be arbitrary. Since $f(x)=f(\frac x2+\frac x2)=f(\frac x2)^2$ it must be positive; take $f(x)=n/m$ in lowest terms.

Suppose that $n/m\ne 1$; then there is some prime $p$ that divides either $n$ or $m$. Suppose it is $p\mid n$; the other case is similar. Let $k$ be some integer such that $p^k>n$. Then what can $f(\frac{x}{k})$ be?
\We know that $f(x) = f(k\frac{x}{k}) = f(\frac{x}{k})^k$. But if $f(\frac{x}{k})=a/b$ in lowest terms, then we must have $a^k=n$. Since $p$ divides $n$, $p$ must divide $a$ too, but then $p^k$ divides $a^k=n$, which contradicts $p^k$ being larger than $n$.

Answer (score 2):

Consider some such homomorphism $f$. Consider an arbitrary element $a/b \in \mathbb{Q}$. If $f(a/b)=p/q$, we can write $p/q$ in lowest terms and get a unique prime factorization $p/q = \frac{p_1^{r_1} \dots p_n^{r_n}}{{q_1^{s_1} \dots q_m^{s_m}}}$. the $p_1 \dots p_n, q_1 \dots q_m$ are distinct prime numbers, and the $r_1 \dots r_n, s_1 \dots s_m$ are positive integers. If $p/q$ is an integer, then the denominator contains no factors, and if $p/q=1$, the numerator contains no factors either. Now, we suppose $p/q \neq 1$. Then consider $k=\min\{r_1, \dots , r_n, s_1, \dots, s_m\}$. Then $f\left(\frac{a}{b(k+1)}\right) = \frac{p_1^{r_1/{k+1}} \dots p_n^{r_n/{k+1}}}{q_1^{s_1/{k+1}} \dots q_m^{s_n/{k+1}}}$. If this value were equal to a rational number $p'/q'$, then we would have $p'^{k+1}/{q'}^{k+1} =p/q$. But any prime factor in $p'^{k+1}/{q'}^{k+1}$ must have power at minimum $k+1$, and since $p/q$ contains a prime of power $k$ and prime factorization is unique by the fundamental theorem of arithmetic, we have a contradiction.

As the only assumption we made was that $\{p_1, \dots , p_n, q_1, \dots q_m\}$ was nonempty, this means that $f(a/b)=1$. But since $a/b$ was arbitrary, $f(x)= 1 \forall x \in \mathbb{Q}$.

Answer (score 1):

There is only the trivial morphism $x \mapsto 1$.

Indeed, we can check that for any $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $x\in \mathbb{Q}$, we have $f(nx)=f(x)^n$.

In particular, since $f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^n = f(1)$, the number $f(1)$ has a rational $n^{\textrm{th}}$ root for all $n \ge 1$. So $f(1) = 1$ and $f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) = 1$ for all $n \ge 1$. And from that we deduce $f\left(\frac{a}{b}\right) = 1^a = 1$.

EDIT : Here's an explanation of my statement that $1$ is the only rational number with a rational $n^{\textrm{th}}$ root for all $n \ge 1$.

Any non zero rational number can be uniquely written as a product of powers of primes (with some negatives exponents, for example $\frac{4}{15} = 2^2 . 3^{-1} . 5^{-1}$). Let $p$ be a prime number, for $x \in \mathbb{Q}^*$ denote $v_p(x) \in \mathbb{Z}$ the exponent of $p$ in this decomposition (called the $p$-adic valuation). We see that $v_p(xy) = v_p(x) + v_p(y)$ for $x, y \in \mathbb{Q}^*$, so in particular $v_p(x^n) = n v_p(x)$. This means **the $p$-adic valuation of an $n^{\textrm{th}}$ power is a multiple of $n$**.

So if $x \in \mathbb{Q}^*$ is an $n^{\textrm{th}}$ power for all $n \ge 1$, then $v_p(x)$ is a multiple of $n$ for all $n \ge 1$, which means $v_p(x) = 0$. And since this is true for all prime numbers $p$, we get $x = 1$.

Comment: Why is $1$ the only rational with a rational nth root for all $n\ge 1$?

Answer (score 1):

Two proofs that there are no nontrivial homomorphisms.

This is kind of the same thing as what others have suggested, but in more abstract terms: ${\bf Q}$ is a divisible group. The image by a homomorphism of a divisible group is always divisible (this is easy to show), but ${\bf Q}^*$ has no nontrivial divisible subgroups (every nonzero rational is not an $n$-th power for a sufficiently large $n$), so the only homomorphism is the trivial one.

For a slightly convoluted, but perhaps interesting proof, it is not very hard to see that ${\bf Q}^*$ is isomorphic (as a group) to the product of the two-element group (corresponding to the sign) and a countably infinitely generated free abelian group (corresponding to the prime decomposition). By noticing that $f(x)=f(x/2)^2$, we see that the image of the homomorphism is a subgroup of the positive rationals, which form a free abelian group under multiplication.

But a subgroup of a free abelian group is always free, and moreover a free generator cannot be divisible (this is a simple consequence of the definition), so the image must be trivial (because it is free and divisible), and so must the homomorphism itself.

This shows that *no* divisible group (even divisible by $2$, say, or any other prime) admits a nontrivial homomorphism into ${\bf Q}^*$.